# Rails 3.1: Why is rails_admin causing `rake asset:precompile` to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## EDIT

This question should be: **Why is rails_admin causing `rake asset:precompile` to fail?**

I'm upgrading from Rails 3.0 to 3.1 and enabling the asset pipeline. Somewhere along the way, rails_admin broke my asset precompiling:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Undefined variable: "$red".
       (in /tmp/build_zkm1tzzdhdh6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails_admin-a887eee6e916/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/base/theming.css.scss)
   
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
```

What's going on here? `$red` is defined (in a different rails_admin .css file). So why isn't `theming.css.scss` able access it? How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed this in the file config/environments/production.rb:
I replaced the line

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']
```

to another

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(rails_admin/rails_admin.css rails_admin/rails_admin.js)
```

This solution is working for ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.1

Comment: Same here. Though not posted, this is the solution I went with.

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom What version rails you using?

Comment: @NikolayMoskvin right, in another post they discussed that it's rails 2.0 that's the issue - switched to 1.9.3 and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the complaint isn't in base.css - the stack trace says the problem was in /app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/base/theming.css.scss. That's where the variable $red is called.

Precompiling assets looks at all your CSS sheets individually, in a bubble - *then* stitches them together into one big chunk. That's why it fails - the `$red` variable doesn't show up in the individual sheet, even though it would show up in the compiled version.

You can fix this in one of two ways: replace the `$red` in theming.css.scss with an actual color code, or you can move your variables into a file and import that file. In my app, for example, I've put all my color variables into "color_codes.css.scss". Then, in any stylesheet where I need to reference them, I add the line `@import "color_codes";` to the top of the sheet.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! Few things: 1) There is no file "/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/base/theming.css.scss", so I assume that is created on-the-fly from "base.css" et al; 2) If assumption's correct, then how/why does "base.css" even reference "$red"?

Comment: Also, I like your "color_codes" style for rails in general, but I don't want to have to edit/maintain code inside "rails_admin", which was generated when I installed the "rails_admin" gem. So I'm not going to use that solution just yet.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see the front of that file path - I didn't realize this was code that came with a gem. It's not being compiled on-the-fly from base.css; it's actually being referenced by the gem itself in a directory completely outside your Rails app. It looks like the RailsAdmin gem has some hiccups when it comes to precompiling assets in general. There's a long discussion thread here that may help: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/682 .

Comment: Thanks again, Mark. That discussion thread isn't my problem, but it's very similar. I was able to figure out my problem and I have posted my own answer to this question.

Comment: FYI: this answer was very helpful in discovering what the problem actually was, but it has become off-topic because I severely edited my original question.

Answer (score 3):

Whoa! I found the problem -- it's a [known issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Known-issues) on Heroku.

You can't blanket-include the rails_admin .css or .js files. i.e.:

- make sure you don't have any catch-all *.(css|js) in
  `config.assets.precompile`
- make sure you don't have any catch-all
  `require_tree .` in `application.(css|js)`

My problem is that I'm doing the former. That's causing my css files to be loaded in isolation, so that variables, like `$red`, aren't shared correctly between them.